# Can't see the elements of the dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I created a navigation bar. Now I want to expand this bar to include a dropdown menu.
Here is a **[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lf0wpvz/)**.

If I hover over the last element, I can't see the dropdown bar (`class="dropdown_ul"`).  And if I use "examine element" I see that the CSS changes the display of the `dropdown_ul`, but I cant see/find it.

```css
.float_left {
    float: left;
}
.float_right {
    float: right;
}
.clear_both {
    clear: both;
}
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family:"Oswald", sans-serif;
}
body {
    background-color: #E2DCDC;
}
nav {
    width: 994px;
    background-color: #77BCF1;
    border: 3px solid white;
    margin: 45px auto;
    color: black;
}
nav > .navigationbar_ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0px;
}
nav > .navigationbar_header {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.navigationbar_li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navigationbar_li_left {
    border-right: 3px solid white;
}
.navigationbar_li_right {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: 3px solid white;
}
.navigationbar_li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.navigationbar_li > .navigationbar_a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.navigationbar_li > .navigationbar_a:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
.dropdown_ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
.dropdown_li {
    display: block;
}
.navigationbar_li:hover .dropdown_ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="navigationbar_ul">
        <div class="float_left">
            <li class="navigationbar_li navigationbar_li_left"><a class="navigationbar_a" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="navigationbar_li navigationbar_li_left"><a class="navigationbar_a" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="float_right">
            <li class="navigationbar_li navigationbar_li_right"><a class="navigationbar_a" href="#">Link 3</a>
                <ul class="dropdown_ul">
                    <li class="dropdown_li"><a class="dropdown_a">Link 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_both"></div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have specified font-size 0 here

```
nav > .navigationbar_ul {
 font-size: 0px;
}
```

Change the `0px` to i.e. `14px` and you will see the text.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought its only on the class `navigationbar_ul` and not on the child elements too.

Answer (score 1):

You got to do 3 things.

Semantically it is wrong to add div in ul right after, instead of li. So remove `.float_left` and `.float_left` divs and add this class to li itself.

Add `position: relative;` to `.navigationbar_li_right` so that absolutely positioned `.dropdown_ul` will display right down like a drop down menu as you have asked.

Increase the `font-size` when you hover `.navigationbar_li_right`

http://jsfiddle.net/6Lf0wpvz/4/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Its perfect^^ & Thanks for the mistake with the `div's` inside the `ul`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Change `.navigationbar_li:hover .dropdown_ul` to:

```
.navigationbar_li:hover .dropdown_ul {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

You need to add `!important` in order to override the previous `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`

By the way, you might as well ditch the `visibility:hidden` when declaring `display:none`

Hope this helps!

Comment: @NiravZaveri: Edited my answer - this should do it, just added some `!important` overrides